# How can I disable GitHub Copilot in VS Code?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I looked on the GitHub website and it says to click on a git icon at the buttom of screen but I don't have that. Is there any other way to disable this annoying notification:

[image: screenshot of the error popup]

It says:

> GitHub Copilot could not connect to server. Extension activation failed: "No access to GitHub Copilot found."

Answer (score 10):

#### Specific features for GitHub Copilot

See [the official enable/disable docs](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/getting-started-with-github-copilot?tool=vscode#enabling-or-disabling-github-copilot-1). TL;DR there's a status bar indicator for GitHub Copilot in VS Code, and upon clicking it, you will be prompted to disable it globally or just for the specific [language mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers) of your currently active editor tab (see the `github.copilot.enable` setting, which takes an object mapping language modes to booleans for whether Copilot should be enabled for editor tabs in the language mode).

There's also a command you can bind to a keyboard shortcut: `github.copilot.toggleCopilot`.

For excluding files from GitHub Copilot, see [How to Exclude Specific Files (like .env) from GitHub Copilot in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77780462/11107541).

You may also be interested in [[Idea] AI actions should respect Copilot Completions language disablement #199379](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/199379).

If you just want to disable automatically showing inline completions, then use the `github.copilot.editor.enableAutoCompletions` setting.

#### General disablement of VS Code extensions

To disable an extension, go to the extensions view. You can do that under the "View" menu at the top left, or click the icon at the left bar, or use the `View: Show Extenstions` command, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> (on Windows and Linux).

Here are pictures of the extension button icon that you can see in the left bar:
[image: light/extensions.svg] [image: dark/extensions.svg]

Then scroll until you find the Github Co-pilot extension, then click the gear icon at the bottom right of the extension card. Then, in the menu that pops up, click "Disable" or if you only want to disable it for the current workspace, "Disable (Workspace)".

Here are pictures of the gear button icon that you can see at the bottom right of the extension card:
[image: light/gear.svg] [image: dark/gear.svg]

Comment: Much more difficult than paying for a Copilot subscription. Oh wait...

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+shift+p >enable copilot

Then you can see the icon in the low right crossed or not...