# How to Exclude Specific Files (like .env) from GitHub Copilot in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, security, environment-variables, github-copilot

I'm currently using GitHub Copilot in Visual Studio Code and am trying to find a way to prevent Copilot from accessing certain file types, specifically `.env` files, which contain sensitive information. I attempted to disable Copilot for these files by adding 'env' and '.env' to the list of disabled files in the Copilot settings, but this approach didn't work, presumably because these aren't recognized as distinct language tags in VS Code.

Has anyone successfully found a way to exclude specific files or file types from GitHub Copilot's analysis? If so, could you please share how you achieved this?

Comment: There's a discussion about a [.copilotignore](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/10305) file to configure files that copilot should ignore, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

In your VS Code user `settings.json` file,

1. Add `.env*` to the `files.associations` object
2. Update the `github.copilot.enable` object

Example:

```json
"files.associations": {
    ".env*": "dotenv"
},
"github.copilot.enable": {
    "*": true,
    // ...
    "dotenv": false,
}
```

To validate, open a test `.env` file.  See that the Copilot icon has a slash over it.

Consider the limitations from https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/managing-copilot-business/configuring-content-exclusions-for-github-copilot#limitations whether they apply, and if they do, how they may apply in this case.

> - Excluding content from GitHub Copilot currently only affects code completion. GitHub Copilot Chat is not affected by these settings.
> - Content exclusion prevents Copilot directly accessing the content of excluded files. Copilot may draw information about non-excluded files from semantic information provided by the IDE - for example, type information, or hover-over definitions for symbols used in code. It's possible that the IDE may derive this information from excluded files.

Comment: see my answer post. pretty sure this will only work if you have an extension installed that contributes a language named "dotenv", and if there is, it probably already contributes that file association.

Comment: @starbull is right, so instead I associate ".env*" with "plaintext", which is a built-in language identifier.

Answer (score 0):

For disabling by [language mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers), see [How can I disable GitHub Copilot in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75377406/11107541). TL;DR click Copilot icon with file open, and select to disable for current language / use the `github.copilot.enabled` setting.

For example, for .env files, since VS Code doesn't have a builtin language mode for envfiles, you could install an extension that adds such language support (Ex. [`mikestead.dotenv`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mikestead.dotenv) <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>), and then add `dotenv` to the list of disabled language modes for GitHub copilot.

---

For disabling by path, currently, you can only do this if you're using GitHub Copilot for Business. You have to configure in in GitHub, either applying it to a repo or an org, and **it will only apply to people part of your Business subscription**. The pattern format is YAML with globbing.

See the following sources:

- https://github.blog/changelog/2023-11-08-copilot-content-exclusion-is-now-available-in-public-beta/
- https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/managing-copilot-business/configuring-content-exclusions-for-github-copilot
- https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/managing-copilot-business/configuring-content-exclusions-for-github-copilot#propagating-content-exclusion-changes-to-vs-code

You can find related community discussion in the following, but at the moment there's not much other info there:

- [Option for disabling Copilot in specific files #11254](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/11254)
- [.copilotignore support #10305](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/10305)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as to how to disable github copilot on all .env files

Answer (score 0):

To ignore files, you've to have an enterprise account.
Basically, if you're owner of an organization.

1. In the upper-right corner of GitHub.com, select your profile photo, then click  Your organizations.
   [image]
2. Next to the organization, click Settings.
3. In the left sidebar, click  Copilot then click Content exclusion.
4. In the box under "Repositories and paths to exclude," enter details of where Copilot should be excluded.

> "*":
> - "**/.env"

For more information:
https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/managing-copilot-business/configuring-content-exclusions-for-github-copilot