How to disable Copilot only on jupiter notebook in VSCode?
How can I disable Copilot such that it stills complete my python code  when I am writing my .py and disable it for jupyter notebooks?
I got some huge slow down when jupyter and copilot are running side by side and I would like to disable copilot by default when a notebook is runnning. I saw  that I can enable copilot in some specified languages but  I can't disable it for notebooks specifically.
I don't want to disable copilot completely I want it to be disable only when Jupyter Notebook are runnings or opened

semi-related, but not answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78428481/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/75377406/11107541

github.copilot.enable. The vscode Language Identifiers does not have jupyter, disable the extension directly.

On VS code in the bottom right there is a GH copilot status icon. Click that icon and then choose to disable completions.
